# Sign-Gordon Equation

Tags: differential-equations, ap.analysis-of-pdes

What can be said and done about the "SIGN-Gordon equation"?
$$\varphi_{tt}- \varphi_{xx} + \text{sgn}(\varphi) = 0.$$ 
It came up [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22281/can-i-relate-the-l1-norm-of-a-function-to-its-fourier-expansion/).

Comment: Rescale $x$, then rescale $t$ identically so the derivatives both get the same constant multipliers. The constants that pop out don't affect the signum, so you can rescale $\varphi$. So this is a kind of scaling limit of sinh-Gordon.

Comment: I thought about that but sinh would scale like O(\phi) in the small  limit while sgn(\phi) scales like O(1). Thanks for the idea of scaling though.

Comment: Jim, Kaveh is talking about the sgn function, not the sin function.  (That is, it's a pun on the sine-Gordon equation.)

Comment: Sorry, I was distracted by the header and didn't look far enough into the question.    Some of my colleagues have been fond of sine-Gordon,
but I'm an outsider.   

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out it appears in literature as the "signum-Gordon equation". For example the paper 
[Signum-Gordon wave equation and its self-similar solutions](http://th-www.if.uj.edu.pl/acta/vol38/pdf/v38p3099.pdf)