# Integral involving exponential of fractional power

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

Can anything be said about the Fourier integral

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[ika - (\gamma + ik)^{2/3}\right]dk$

where $a > 0$ and $\gamma > 0$?

Can it be related to some special function? It appears in the physics application described [in this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22281/can-i-relate-the-l1-norm-of-a-function-to-its-fourier-expansion).

Comment: Closed form for the case $k=1,\gamma=0$ is not found by Maple 13.

Comment: He did say gamma > 0.  I'm almost positive it converges to a real value when alpha = gamma = 1, as the imaginary part cancels itself out (limit of the imaginary component's integral from -a to a as a goes to infinity is zero, as it's an odd function).  I wouldn't be surprised if this was the case for all alpha and gamma.  I'll do some more experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upon a change of variables, $\gamma+ik\mapsto ik'$ it takes the form of the generating function of a socalled stable distribution (with stability parameter $\alpha=2/3$
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution